auth0 logout exception: “a0.authentication_canceled: The user closed the browser app so the logout was cancelled.”
I’m trying to logout from auth0 using auth0_flutter, but instead getting exception from the title.
Before exception I see this URL in log, which seems fine to me:

D/LogoutManager(25194): Using the following Logout URI:
AUTH0_DOMAIN/v2/logout?auth0Client=Auth0Client%3D&returnTo=AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI&client_id=AUTH0_CLIENT_ID

This is my logout implementation:
await _auth0
     .webAuthentication(scheme: _environmentParamsService.getScheme())
     .logout(
        returnTo: _environmentParamsService.getAuth0RedirectUrl()
     );

And here is a code for login:
await _auth0.webAuthentication(
        scheme: _environmentParamsService.getScheme()
    ).login(
        audience: _environmentParamsService.getAudience(),
        parameters: {
          'prompt': 'login',
        }
    );

Any tips please?
